# My hook-form is simply not working. It is not preventing default neither showing my error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, yup

I'm tring to perform a verification for each input box so the people subscribing cannot leave it blank but when i press 'submit' it is submiting even when it has wrong data or no data at all. I've been reading this code for hours but i cannot figure out what's going on. I have other code which i'm doing - aparrently - the exact same thing and it is working jus tfine

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { FormStyled } from "../../styles/form";
import { RegisterLoginContext } from "../../contexts/contexRegisterLogin";

interface IRegisterData {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConfirmation: string;
  name: string;
  userName: string;
  url: string;
  birthDate: string;

}
export const FormRegister = () => {
  const { modalOnRegister, setModalOnRegister }: any =
    useContext(RegisterLoginContext);

  
    const schema = yup.object({
      name: yup.string().required("Por favor digite seu nome"),
  
      email: yup
        .string()
        .required("por favor digite seu email")
        .email("Digite um email valido"),
  
      password: yup
        .string()
        .required("digite uma senha")
        .matches(/^(?=.*\d)/, "Necessario ao menos um numero")
        .matches(/(?=.*[a-z])/, "necessita ao menos uma letra ")
        .matches(/(?=.*[$*&@#])/, "necessita ao menos um simbolo")
        .matches(/[0-9a-zA-Z$*&@#]{8,}$/, "necessita no minimo 8 digitos"),
  
      userName: yup
        .string()
        .required("Por favor digite seu nome de usuário"),
  
      url: yup
      .string().url("Url informada não é válida")
      .required("Esse campo não pode ficar vázio"),
  
      birthDate: yup.string().required("O campo de data não pode ficar vazio"),
  
  
      passwordConfirmation: yup
        .string()
        .oneOf([yup.ref("password")], "As senhas não correspondem verifique")
        .required(),
    });
  
    const {
      register,
      handleSubmit,
      formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<IRegisterData>({
      resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    });
    

    const test = () => {
      console.log('foi')
    }
  return (
    <FormStyled>
      <button
        className="closeModal"
        onClick={() => setModalOnRegister(!modalOnRegister)}
      >
        X
      </button>
        <div className="HeaderForm">
          <h2>Subscribe</h2>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(test)}>
        <div className="Inpults">
          <input type="text" id="name" {...register("name")} />
          <label htmlFor="name">Nome</label>
          <span>{errors.name?.message}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="Inpults">
          <input type="text" id="username" {...register("userName")} />
          <label htmlFor="username">Nome de usuário</label>
        </div>
        <div className="Inpults">
          <input type="email" id="Email" {...register("email")} />
          <label htmlFor="Email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div className="Inpults">
          <input type="password" id="password" {...register("password")} />
          <label htmlFor="password">Senha</label>
        </div>
        <div className="Inpults">
          <input type="password" id="passwordConfirm" {...register("passwordConfirmation")} />
          <label htmlFor="passwordConfirm">Confirme sua senha</label>
        </div>
        <div className="Inpults">
          <input type="text" id="profilePicture" {...register("url")} />
          <label htmlFor="profilePicture">Link da foto de perfil</label>
        </div>
        <div className="Inpults">
          <input type="date" id="birthdate" {...register("birthDate")} />
          <label htmlFor="birthdate">Data de nascimento</label>
        </div>
        <button className="buttonLogin" type="submit">
          Criar conta
        </button>
        </form>
    </FormStyled>
  );
};
```